# New origin of imshow after set_data()

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, imshow

i have a very strange problem. After setting the data of my imshow instace, the origin is changed from 'upper' to 'lower' and i did not manage to reverse it again. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
im = ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_xlim(0, new_data.shape[1])
ax.set_ylim(0, new_data.shape[0])
im.set_extent((0, new_data.shape[1], 0, new_data.shape[0]))
im.set_data(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 works, but a more direct way without `set_extent` is to reverse the y-axis:

```
im = ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_xlim(0, new_data.shape[1])
ax.set_ylim(0, new_data.shape[0])
ax.invert_yaxis()
# im.set_extent((0, new_data.shape[1], 0, new_data.shape[0]))
im.set_data(new_data)
```

or, change to `imshow` origin to non-default 'lower':

```
im = ax.imshow(data,origin='lower')
ax.set_xlim(0, new_data.shape[1])
ax.set_ylim(0, new_data.shape[0])
# im.set_extent((0, new_data.shape[1], 0, new_data.shape[0]))
im.set_data(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Just swap the values in set_extent() and leave out the set_xim and set_ylim :

```
im = ax.imshow(data)
im.set_extent((0, new_data.shape[1], new_data.shape[0], 0))
im.set_data(new_data)
```